# Using parameter in stored procedure to get dynamic table name

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I already wrote a pretty complex stored procedure, but now i want to bring some dynamics into the procedures using variables. I still call myself a newbiew when it comes to sql programming, so i might be totally on the wrong way with what i'd like to achieve.
I am running the latest MySQL server 8.0.13 on windows (just for local dev).

My current idea for the stored procedure
... uses an input variable
... declares a cursor (using the var)
... create a temp table (using the var)
... iterates through the temp table
... write data to a new table

I think i understand some of the basic tools to do that but i fail again and again with handling the variable(s)
The following code shows the top part of the project where i already fail.

```
 PROCEDURE sprProcedure (
  IN vInputParameter varchar(64)
 )
 BEGIN
  DECLARE vFinished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

  -- declare cursor
  DECLARE cCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM tbltmp_(vInputParameter);
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET vFinished = 1;

  -- drop / create temp table
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS (vInputParameter);
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbltmp_(vInputParameter)
   SELECT * FROM `tbl_DataSource`;
```

... did not paste any further code as i can't deal with the following issue.

I tried
... using the variable directly > variable is not resolved in `DECLARE CURSOR` statement
... define `user-defined` variable before `local-variables` is not allowed
... `CONCAT`'ed the string to build a statement and `EXECUTE`'ed it > does not work in the `DECLARE`part of the stored procedure

At this point i am totally open to every hint or totally new ideas about how to approach this.

Thanks for any advice!

**[Update]**
My approach up there has some flaws and i did not understand the basic concept of temp tables for example being unique to the session. Thanks to 'D's Query' and a little more reading i now have a working stored procedure without having to deal with dynamic names of cursors and temp tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what actually you are focusing on but loading a dynamic tables can be possible with prepared statements in Stored Procedures but prepared statements won't work with CURSORS.

Example of Prepared statement is

```
SET $sql=CONCAT('SELECT * from ', var_tablename);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: The reason for naming the temptable based on the parameter and then having to create the cursor using the dynamic temptable name was just the idea of preventing to have 2 identical temptables at the time. I guess if 2 users happen to call this function at the same time this will probably end in an error right?

Comment: Temporary tables are not single table which is accessible by all the users.Temporary tables are session specific. If two users try to access one storedprocedure or function at the same time then they will have a different copy of temporary tables. I would suggest you to go through the basic concept of temporary tables.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that fact. I did indeed not read that far into the documentation of temporary tables and will now spend some more time over there.